# How can I stop react from starting MetaMask on Dapp load

Tags: web3js, blockchain, metamask, react

Blockchain newbie.

If I place the contract JS in my React App, MetaMask always starts when the Dapp loads.

```
import donboard from "./donboard";
```

However, if I remove the import line, I can rely on the below code to help me connect with MetaMask when user clicks the button.

```
onSubmit = async (event) => {
event.preventDefault();
if (window.ethereum) {
  window.web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);
  try {
    window.ethereum.enable();
    const accounts = await window.ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_accounts' });
    const account = accounts[0];
    this.setState({ account });
    console.log("async onSubmit: " + account);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("not connected-onSubmit: " + err);
  }
}};
```

As I will need the contract JS once user is connected, how can I resolve this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by ***not*** exporting the contract

```
export default new web3.eth.Contract(abi, address);
```

, but just  bringing the loading of the ABI and address into a conditional when the required button is pressed.